# Regex for letters, digits, no spaces

Tags: objective-c, regex

I'm trying to create a Regex to check for 6-12 characters, one being a digit, the rest being any characters, no spaces.  Can Regex do this?  I'm trying to do this in objective-c and I'm not familiar with Regex at all.  I've been reading a couple tutorials, but most are for matching simple cases of a number, or a set of numbers, but not exactly what i'm looking for. I can do it with methods, but I was wondering if it that would be too slow and I figured I could try learning something new.

```
asdfg1 == ok
asdfg 1 != ok
asdfgh != ok
123456 != ok
asdfasgdasgdasdfasdf != ok
```

Comment: Does the digit have to come at the end?  or can it be anywhere in the string?  When you say "any characters" do you mean just letters or digits/symbols as well?

Comment: @Snowsickle It can come anywhere.

Comment: Why does your title say "digits" and your question says "one digit"? What exactly does "any characters" mean? Does it include digits? Punctuation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you mean "letter" when you say "character", right? And (thanks to burning_LEGION for pointing that out) there may be only one digit?

In that case, use

```
^(?=\D*\d\D*$)[^\W_]{6,12}$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^             # Start of string
(?=\D*\d\D*$) # Assert that there is exactly one digit in the string
[^\W_]        # Match a letter or digit (explanation below)
{6,12}        # 6-12 times
$             # End of string
```

`[^\W_]` might look a little odd. How does it work? Well, `\w` matches any letter, digit or underscore. `\W` matches anything that `\w` doesn't match. So `[^\W]` (meaning "match any character that is not not alphanumeric/underscore") is essentially the same as `\w`, but by adding `_` to this character class, we can remove the underscore from the list of allowed characters.

Comment: @tim Doesn't that allow 6 digits without any characters? 123456 != ok http://regexpal.com/

Comment: @burning_LEGION: You're right, I didn't notice that digits-only is not allowed. I wonder why my answer was accepted, then. Well, I've edited it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

use this regex `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[^ ]{6,12}$`

Comment: Your regex allows spaces and other non-alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't try though, but i think here is the answer

```
(^[^\d\x20]*\d[^\d\x20]*$){6,12}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for one digit:   `^[^\d\x20]{0,11}\d{1}[^\d\x20]{0,11}$` but I can`t get limited to 6-12 length, you can use other function to check length first and if it from 6 to 12 check with this regex witch I wrote.